# How can I set attributes to li tags in CheckboxSelectMultiple?

Tags: python, html, django

I used CheckboxSelectMultiple as a widget for MultipleChoiceField.
I know it makes something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="..." ></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

when I set an attribute to CheckboxSelectMultiple, django adds it to ul tag.
my question is, how can I set attributes to li?

Comment: what kind of attributes that you set to? maybe you can do it with javascript in case the attributes values do not come from any model

Comment: @Lemayzeur there's another ul tag with some li tags in page. so it's not easy to use javascript because I don't want to set attributes to them.

Comment: @Lemayzeur I want to add a bootstrap class. class="list-group-item"

Comment: I would avoid the modification of the html generated by django.
I'd do with the id of the field: `$("#id_checkboxselectmulitplefield .li").addClass("li-group-item")`. or with pure js `Document.querySelector("#d_checkboxselectmulitplefield .li).setAttrinutes("class","list-group-item");` Even   though you have other ul tag, there would not be any problem if you target it with the `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed that way

Django provides a ul list for `MultipleChoiceField`. I give you an example since I do not have any clue of your codes

**forms.py**

```
OPTIONS = (
    ("B", "Black"),
    ("Y", "Yellow"),
    ("R", "Red"),
)
colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=OPTIONS)
```

send the form to the template through `your_view`

**template.html**

you would have called it like with `{{form.colors}}`. This way will let django generates its pre-built html, whereas you can loop through it:

```
<ul>
{% for check in form.colors %}
    <li class='your class'>{{check.tag}} <!-- this is the checkbox input generated by django -->
    <label for="{{check.id_for_label}}">{{check.choice_label}}</label></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```